# Windows Update Properties - Access Denied (as Administrator)

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-update, automatic-update

I'm trying to set the startup type to Automatic in Windows Update Properties of Windows 10, but the error "Access denied" appears.
How can I fix it?

I tryed also with the command "Net user administrator /active:yes" in the Prompt; the administrator modality is activated, but I get the same error when I try to do the forementioned action.

[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you doing and what is the error. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1498848/edit) your post to add the information. Screenshots might help.

Comment: Hello @harrymc, I want to update windows, but it does not work. I edited my question by inserting a screenshot, but it is in italian.

Comment: Why not go through Start > Settings > Windows Update settings*?

Comment: See the other screenshot please.

Comment: You meant the system service wuauserv

Comment: Idk wuauserv; what is it?

Comment: The Windows Update system service.

Comment: Just an FYI, Local Administrator account is not required and should remain inactive and disabled, as it's a security risk to have it enabled since it's SID is well known.  I could be wrong, but `wuauserv` isn't meant to be Auto started, but trigger started manually.  As @harrymc mentioned, Settings should be utilized to force an update, however if you're trying to force upgrade to a bi-annual update, it won't always show up even though all prereqs are installed - simply use [Microsoft's link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to force it, clicking on Update Now

Comment: You will need to translate the text in the screenshot.

Comment: Hello @JW0914 your commend fixes my problem; now windows update works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the the registry keys had been corrupted to set the startup to disabled, and the registry keys were set to READ ONLY.
The 2 keys I had to fix were:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaaSMedicSvc

Change ownership of the registry keys to be ADMINISTRATORS and then change permissions so SYSTEM has full control did the trick.
how to do this:
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-of-registry-keys-and-assign-full-permissions/

After that, I was able to change the two services back to automatic start, and windows update began working again.

Comment: Include the details from the link in your answer.

Comment: You've made my day, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Update Startup type in Windows 10 is Manual, and there is no need
to change it to Automatic for it to work.
Actually, changing the Startup type to "Automatic" or "Automatic (Delayed Start)"
might cause it to malfunction if it starts too early.

It is also doubtful whether such a change will keep, because Windows 10 surveys
periodically the settings of Windows Update and will restore them from
time to time.

If you wish to try and change this setting:

- Start `regedit`
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv`
- Change `Start` to:

  - Automatic : 2
  - Manual : 3
  - Disabled : 4
  - Automatic (Delayed Start) : 2